# old question - but unsolved: no result SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_datetime_field BETWEEN start AND end

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb, between, php-5.6

I have some code to query a MariaDB with PHP 5.6.38 and PDO. The Databsase and the Code works fine, but if I use the BETWEEN Operator together with two DateTimes, the Code gives no result - that means Null - and no Error - no Exception - always Null. The field type inside MariaDB is DATETIME. The format stored inside the DB is '2019-05-06 14:16:32'.

I have tried many tips from stackoverflow. The problem seams old and well known, but I got no solution at this time. My current code looks like this:

(example code to test the problem with a simple webserver)

```php
<?php

$cal = new Calendar();

var_dump($cal->GetDatabaseEvents('2019-06-01T00:00:00+200', '2019-06-10T23:59:59+200'));

class Calendar {

  private $dbh;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar', 'mytable', 'mypwd');
    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }


  public function GetDatabaseEvents($start, $end) {
    $sql ="SELECT id, datetime_begin FROM events WHERE datetime_begin BETWEEN '2019-06-00T00:00:00' AND '2019-06-10T23:59:59'";
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    if($count = $sth->execute()) {
      while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
        echo some member of $row...
      }
    } else {
      echo "SQL Error <br />";
      echo $sth->queryString."<br />";
      echo $sth->errorInfo()[2];        
    }
  }
}
```

there is no Error or Exception. All results are NULL. If i delete the FROM part from the SQL, the Statement works fine and give a result as excpected.

I've tried many other tricks like 
a) CAST('2019-01-05T00:00:00', DATE or DATETIME) or 
b) no ISO DateTime like this '2019-01-05 00:00:00' with CAST und without CAST or 
c) no BETWEEN but (`datetime_begin` >= begin AND `datetime_begin` <= end) or
d) parameter binding like $sth->bindParam(':start_date', $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);

but all results are NULL

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: The `T` is the problem.  MySQL does not recognize that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> The format stored inside the DB is '2019-05-06 14:16:32'

Databases stored date/time values using an *interval* format.  This leads me to think that you are using a string -- and string comparisons.

I also find it confusing that you are referring to the zero day of the month, although I think MySQL/MariaDB allows this.

I would recommend:

```
WHERE datetime_begin >= '2019-06-01' AND
      datetime_begin < '2019-06-11'
```

Comment: - ok - thank you: your example is no string? what is '2019-06-01' in your example? it seems like a string?
- the zero day is an error, i mean 2019-06-01 or any other valid datetime

Comment: That is a string that is treated as a date constant in the query.

Comment: yes - of course - thats not my problem - my problem is, how can i get up and running my SQL Statement? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If your actual data is '2019-05-06 14:16:32', it is not BETWEEN '2019-06-00T00:00:00' AND '2019-06-10T23:59:59' : May 6 BETWEEN June 00 AND June 10.

Otherwise, I copy pasted your code, changed the connection string, to match my database, and table name / field to match a table I have with a DATETIME field, and it works fine on php 7.2.16 .

Finally, you are using var_dump() on a function that does not return anything, so you will always get a NULL as the last line in your display.

Comment: thank you - you are all right - i've found the great failure today in the morning - sorry - somebody has overwritten my table in the background and all my efforts were in vain - the datetime fields silently set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and my operator BETWEEN shows the strange behavior - sorry - it's really a shame - sorry